# Сохранить файл в другую директорию

Tags: c#, файлы

У меня есть директория (допустим string pathFile = P:\Database\new) , в которую нужно копировать файл, выбранный пользователем. Начал писать:

```
 private void внестиДанныеToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog opfd = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (opfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string path = opfd.FileName;//этот файл нужно сохранить в заданную заранее директорию

            //?
        }

    }
```

Подскажите, как доработать код, чтобы файл сохранялся в заданную директорию, спасибо.

Comment: @AntonKomyshan Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
File.Copy (path, outPath );
```